# jQuery animate for hash anchor causes back button bug

Tags: jquery

I'm making a web page that has a fixed header, and when the user clicks a navigation link in the header the whole page (html and body) have an animated slide to put that linked element at the top, instead of just jumping there. My problem is that if I try to click the back button, it will be one section behind. For example, if I'm on section #A then go to section #B then section #C, and hit the back button on section #C, it won't go back to page #B until I click it once more. The url reflects the back button being hit, but the page stays the same. So the url will be on #A after hitting 'back' twice but the page will actually be on #B still.

Here's my jQuery code, it's pretty simple. If anyone could help me get back button functionality working I'd appreciate it

```
$('.header-nav-item').click(scrollBody);

function scrollBody(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var url_hash = "#" + e.target.href.substring(e.target.href.indexOf('#')+1);

    $('html,body').animate({
        'scrollTop':   $(url_hash).offset().top
    }, 500,'swing',function(){
        //reroute url
        window.location = url_hash;
    });
}
```

EDIT: this problem happens in Firefox and Chrome. strangely, IE handles the back button just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firefox and Chrome, clicking the back button brings you to your position in the page before the URI changed. Your function that changes `window.location` runs *after* the animation completes, which means the back button brings you to the position where the animation completes.

In your case, these two positions on the page are exactly the same, so it looks like the browser isn't doing anything when you click the back button the first time.

Explained in list format:

1. User clicks the link.
2. Animation scrolls to the anchor, which becomes the previous place in the browser's history when...
3. ... you create a new history item by changing the browser's URL to the anchor.

Here's kind of a hacky solution (I can't think of anything else right now):

```js
$('.header-nav-item').click(scrollBody);

function scrollBody(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var url_hash = "#" + e.target.href.substring(e.target.href.indexOf('#')+1);

    // Browse to the anchor before changing anything (doing the animation) so the back 
    // button gets us to the position the user was viewing before s/he clicked on the 
    // navigation link. We save the original position ($(document).scrollTop()) -- i.e., 
    // where the user was originally -- so we can go back to it to do the animation.
    var orig = $(document).scrollTop();
    window.location.hash = url_hash;
    window.scrollTo(orig);

    $('html,body').animate(
        { 'scrollTop':   $(url_hash).offset().top },
        500,
        'swing'
    );
}
```